# Grails, how can I send a message(type flash) from the domain if I find an error?

Tags: validation, grails, exception

When updating a domain instance I need to check some data before allowing the update.
I made it in the beforUpdate method and it prevents the update but in the flash message you can read "Domain 68 updated!" and that is not what I want to show the user.

The beforeUpdate looks like this:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    def oldVolume =  getPersistentValue('volumeInStock')
    if (oldVolume != volumeInStock && oldVolume!=volumeInitial){
       throw new ValidationException("Changing InStock not allowed after offer/sold or planed volumes added!",this)
    }
}
```

I was thinking about throwing an exception, but that didn't look as easy as I thought. When I tried the code above it says that there are method like that. and I can't find any example or instructions how I should make the call.
So the main question is how can I inform the user about the problem?
Is it the wright way to use exception, then I need some help how to do that or else what else can I do? :(

Comment: try changing `throw new ValidationException("Changing InStock not allowed after offer/sold or planed volumes added!",this)` to    `this.errors.rejectValue('volumeInStock',"failedVolume.error')`

Comment: This does not stop grails from saving the instance, but if I use "return false", that's all I need to stop it to save. But of course I don't get the message - it still says that it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a generic exception handling mechanism for my controllers like the following which works for most scenarios, this might not work for you if you need to do additional stuff other than render the message to the screen.

```
trait ControllerExceptionHandler {

    def handleException( Exception e ) {
        def msg = e.message ?: e?.cause?.message
        flash.fail = msg
        log.info msg
        return
    }
}
```

Then your controllers implement this trait:

```
class MyController implements ControllerExceptionHandler {
    def save() {
        // do something that might throw an exception, if it does the ControllerExceptionHandler will deal with it
        // it worked
        flash.message = message( code: 'default.success.message' )
    }
}
```

In your gsps:

```
<g:render template="/templates/alerts"/>
```

views/templates/_alerts.gsp

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">   
    <g:render template="/templates/message" model="[type: 'info', message: flash.message]" />
</g:if>
<g:if test="${flash.fail}">   
    <g:render template="/templates/message" model="[type: 'danger', message: flash.fail]" />
</g:if>
```

views/templates/_message.gsp

```
<div class="alert alert-${type} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  ${message}
</div>
```

The above makes use of bootstrap styling.

Comment: Ok, but that was step 2. Step 1 was "How should I code the " throw xxxxException('My error message')" in the "beforeUpdate" method?

Comment: TBH I don't use the beforeXXXX etc methods on the domain, I generally do domain non-constraint validation in my services, I think if you changed to e.g. `throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Changing InStock not allowed after offer/sold or planed volumes added!" )` this would work with the above using beforeXXXX, I'm guessing the ValidationException is caught by Grails & isn't propagated back to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

But why do you avoid standard grails validation [mechanism](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/validation.html)?

Just define constraints, `validate()` or `save()`, put errors to `flash` if `hasErrors()`.

Throwing exceptions may break your transactions (if you save in transactional services, that is recommended).